# Combine FAB in the Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, android-layout, android-bottomnav, floating-action-button

I am currently working with Fab and BottomNavigationView. What i want is to combine the two together like this

[image]

This is the code I tried which doesn't look as nearly as nice

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_items"></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView> </RelativeLayout>
```

Any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, what do you mean is the Fab is overlapping the navigation?

Comment: actually it is custom navigation bar

Comment: looking for https://medium.com/material-design-in-action/implementing-bottomappbar-material-components-for-android-f490c4a01708. use material components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_soft" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/map_button"
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:onClick="clickAction"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_near_me" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Map"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_height="0dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="@dimen/spacing_medium">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/list_button"
                    android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:onClick="clickAction"
                    android:tint="@color/colorPrimary"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_format_list_bulleted" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="List"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="clickAction"
        android:tint="@android:color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        app:rippleColor="@color/deep_orange_400"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it looks good, I ran into few errors but I'll have a go at them first

Comment: Your solution has too much boilerplate code, your should use `BottomNavigationBar` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, discovered on accident.

1. Set up your `BottomNavigationView` as usual, under a `ConstraintLayout`. I tried with 3 navigation items in the `menu/nav_menu.xml`, and with an empty middle item
2. Insert a `CoordinatorLayout` under the `ConstraintLayout` and wrap the `BottomAppBar` and `FloatingActionButton` inside so that you can set `app:layout_anchor` in the `FAB`.
3. Depends on where you want the `FAB` to be placed vertically, you can either set `android:layout_height="0dp"`, which makes the entire button *almost* embed into the bottom bar as shown below, or set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, which should match the height of the `BottomNavigationView`, but would create the curve around the `FAB` and you can continue with `app:fabCradleVerticalOffset` to further lift the `FAB`. In the latter case, set `app:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF"` so that the `BottomNavigationView` has a transparent background.

[image]

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" >

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/bottom_app_bar" />

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:backgroundTint="#00FFFFFF" />
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

menu/nav_menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_36"
        android:title="Home"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Placeholder"
        android:checkable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:title="" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_in_tray"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_assignment_36"
        android:title="In-tray"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: You are great :)